# Difference between bending equation of cantilever beam and dynamic equation of motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, definition, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, structural-beam

What is the difference between Bending Equation of cantilever beam and dynamic equation of cantilever beam?

Is it possible to derive one from the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bending equation typically contains no *dynamic terms* i.e., accelerations and velocities because it is used to solve for *static deflections* under the influence of *constant loads*.

Now if we imagine the cantilever beam to be massless and have a point load asserted on its free end, then the constituitive equation for the *compliance* of the beam can be extracted from the bending equation and used as the compliance term in a dynamic analysis of the oscillatory response of a cantilever beam with a point-mass loading.

This could also be done if the loading of the beam is only its own distributed mass, in which case the above *lumped element response model* would be inadequate, and you would have to create a *distributed element response model* instead.